# Image carousel in 10 lines or so

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a PHP/MySQL front end problem. I've set up a loop that returns 20 list items which are images that are stacked horizontally. Now, I'd appreciate help with some jQuery code that does two things:

I. Displays only 4 of the 20 items — image 1, 2, 3, 4.

II. On a click event:

(a) If the <kbd>next</kbd> button is clicked, slide in the next set of four slides into view, i.e. image 5, 6, 7, 8. When <kbd>next</kbd> is clicked again, slide in image 9, 10, 11, 12 and so on.

(b) If the <kbd>previous</kbd> button is clicked, slide in the previous set of four slides...

How can this be done? And if it takes more than 10 lines, please provide the code or links to it.

Comment: check this http://www.walkswithme.net/jquery-cycle-plugin-for-simple-slideshow

Comment: Too bad. I have just what you need but it's 11 lines.

Comment: This is insanely googlable & has probably been asked many many times on SO, so I would delete & start there or you are likely to get downvoted a bunch.

Comment: Please consider growing up. This is not a "code restaurant" as far as I know. What have you tried? Post code with problem, try google-ing first, or searching for similar questions.

Comment: Of course, I've been Googling but all I get are plugins that got over 500 lines of code! From my PHP experience, a problem like this one really doesn't need that many lines..

The reason I've not attempted trying is because I have no idea which jQuery method to use: sort()? filter()? nextAll? I'm clueless.

Comment: *"I have no idea which jQuery method to use: sort()? filter()? nextAll? I'm clueless"* Did you read the jQuery documentation? It explains what those methods do and provides examples and from that you should be able to figure out if you need those methods or not. Or just *try* them and see if you get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you would need to do some css modifications, where the css would only allow 4 of the 20 items to be shown at a time.

```
#image-container { width: 800px; overflow: hidden; }
```

the above code is assuming the image container as the ID , and is assuming that each of the pictures is 200px wide. The overflow hide would then hide anything greater than the 800px , so only four images would show.

Secondly, you would want to use jQuery for the on click event and your code would look something like this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#next-button').click(function(){
        $('img:first-child').animate({left: '-200px'}, 800);
});
});
```

You would have to set this up very precisely and requires a good deal of knowledge of html/css/and jquery. Or you could find a plug in to do most of the hard work for you. The above jQuery code is just an example and what you're trying to do would include at least 3-5 times the amount of jQuery than I posted.

Comment: Ah, that's more like it! I'll take it from there, a point in the right direction was all that I needed. A massive thanks to you, Codehorse.